# How to extract various statistics like teststat and pvalue etc. from ur test output object

Tags: r

I need to run stationarity test for multiple time series. I use the `ur.df` function from the `urca` package to do them. I then store the outputs from each of these `adf` test as a list of lists - as each of these is a list itself.

I need to be able to store all the parameters like from the output in to a data frame. Is there a way to do it?

I know I can extract some of the parameters like the `@teststat`, `@cval` and the like but how do we get out all of the parameters as we can with the `lm` regression output using `broom`

For example, if this is the output from `ur.df` function

```
test1 <- ur.df(usage_1601_1612, type = "none", lags = 1, selectlags = "AIC")
```

The contents of `test1` are shown below

```
Test regression none 

Call:
lm(formula = z.diff ~ z.lag.1 - 1 + z.diff.lag)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-6093.2 -1385.8  -100.9  1414.3  6962.8 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
z.lag.1    -0.004212   0.005191  -0.811   0.4177  
z.diff.lag -0.126685   0.052161  -2.429   0.0156 *
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 2351 on 362 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.01838,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.01296 
F-statistic:  3.39 on 2 and 362 DF,  p-value: 0.03479


Value of test-statistic is: -0.8114 

Critical values for test statistics: 
      1pct  5pct 10pct
tau1 -2.58 -1.95 -1.62
```

This is the general code that I run

```
urresultorigobjects <- 
   lapply(usagextsobjects, function(x) {
     summary(ur.df(x, type = "none", lags = 1, selectlags = "AIC"))
   })
```

This generates the list `urresultorigobjects` containing the outputs from the stationarity test on each of the `xts` objects in the list `usagextsobjects`.

I would like to be able to capture all of the output and store the relevant information in a data frame for code based reference for downstream processing.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Doesn't the object generatted by the `ur.df` have a `$p-value` and other things that can be found by assigning the output, then using the `$` sign?

Comment: Hi RAB <- No, it doesn't, at least I couldn't find it. I could get some of the info like cval and teststat etc but not all as you could with the linear regression output object for which you can use the broom package to extract all of the information contained in the object.

Comment: Any suggestions on this one guys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if there is an easier way but I managed it like this:

```
(ur.df(valdata, type="none", lags=0))@testreg[["coefficients"]][,"Pr(>|t|)"]
```